# how to fix these errors in oracle stored procedure callable statement?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

```
create or replace procedure updateStudentResult(id int)
as
m1 number(4);
m2 number(4);
m3 number(4);
tot number(4);
avg float;
grd char(1);
begin
select marks1,marks2,marks3 into m1,m2,m3 from students where sid=id;
tot:=m1+m2+m3;
avg:=tot/3;
if(avg>=85.0) then
grd:='A';
elsif(avg>=65.0) then
grd:='B';
elsif(avg>=50.0) then
grd:='C';
else
grd:='D';
end if;
update students set total=tot,average=avg,grade=grd where sid=id;
end;
/
```

Comment: am trying to pass sid as id in procedure to calculate the total,average and updating  in the DB STUDENTS

Comment: PL-0103 encountered '=' while expecting the following (

Comment: At which line is that error encountered? Read the entire error message, it is quite helpful! Then, aside from any errors, why are you doing all this in a procedure, and not in a plain SQL `UPDATE` statement? Even better, why don't you save these computations, either in the table itself (as virtual columns) or in a view?

Comment: why this code is not running without compilation problem?

Comment: What is the compilation error, it usually will tell you what and where your problem is?  If you are in sql*plus, run "show errors;" and it will provide the detail.

Comment: @mathguy  am using JDBC callable statement to exe the business logic efficiently in less tym ,stored procedure pre compiles the code soo its fast .can u help me out of this code?

Comment: on line->   if(avg>=85.0) then
,PL-0103 encountered '=' while expecting the following (

Comment: avg is a sql function/reserved word, rename this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the procedural code and the initial select is unnecessary. This will suffice;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updatestudentresult(id INT) AS

BEGIN
  UPDATE students
     SET total = mark1+mark2+mark3,
     average = (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3,
     grd = CASE
           WHEN (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 85 THEN 'A'
           WHEN (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 65 THEN 'B'
           WHEN (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 50 THEN 'C'
           ELSE 'D'
           END
   WHERE sid = id;
END;
```

Comment: 12 seconds and an ocean !

Answer (score 0):

avg is a reserved word (it is a function). You can not use it as a variable name in plsql. Use another variable name for your calculated average.

```
create or replace procedure updatestudentresult(id int) as
   m1  number(4);
   m2  number(4);
   m3  number(4);
   tot number(4);
   l_avg float;
   grd char(1);
begin
   select marks1
         ,marks2
         ,marks3
     into m1
         ,m2
         ,m3
     from students
     where sid = id;

   tot := m1 + m2 + m3;

   l_avg := tot / 3;

   if l_avg > 85.0
   then
      grd := 'A';
   elsif (l_avg >= 65.0)
   then
      grd := 'B';
   elsif (l_avg >= 50.0)
   then
      grd := 'C';
   else
      grd := 'D';
   end if;

   update students
      set total   = tot
         ,average = l_avg
         ,grade   = grd
    where sid = id;
end;
```

Comment: l_avg > 85.0    is this a correct syntax or  (l_avg >= 65.0) which one?

Comment: It should be >= as in your example. You can either write it with () or without.

Comment: ------>>>>>>>  THANKU SO MUCH  @Rene

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can do this in pl/sql, this would probably be better as an updates statement.  Not judgement here on the data model, just using what you have.

```
update students
  set total = mark1+mark2+mark3,
        avg = (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3,
        grd = case 
            WHEN (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 85.0 then 'A'
            when (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 65.0 then 'B'
            when (mark1+mark2+mark3)/3 > 50.0 then 'C'
            else 'D' end 
where  sid = :sid;
```